# 'Smoother' looking teleportation with Vector3.Lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Short version: Can I use `Vector3.Lerp` in `transform.Translate(new Vector3(-6,0));` (without calculating a speed variable into the movement)?

I have a very simple game where the Player can move from 1 lane to another (max. 3 lanes (like Temple Run)). Right now my character is just teleporting to the other lanes and I want to make it look more smooth with `Vector3.Lerp`. My problem now is, I cant figure out how to implement it into my code. I don't calculate my movement with a speed variable, because my character starts moving uneven distances, which I don't want. I have 3 set lanes to move to.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
{             
    // Do I need a speed variable here?
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(-6, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code is not in Update(), you can use StartCoroutine

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("a")) {
    changing = true;
    StartCoroutine(ChangeLane(int n));
}

IEnumerator ChangeLane(int n) {
    float changeProgress = 0f;
    float changeDuration = 1f;
    originPosition = tranform.position;
    //the speed should be run speed
    targetPosition = originPosition + new Vector3(n * lanWidth, speed * changeDuration);

    while(changeProgress < changeDuration) {
        tranform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPosition, targetPosition, changeProgress / changeDuration);
        changeProgress += Time.DeltaTime;
        yield return 0;
    }
    tranform.position = targetPosition;
    changing = false;
}
```

If the code is in Update(), you can also use this, but while changing lane, you should not start a new change